# How to get Sub-Total value of previous page in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

How can I get sub-total value (runningvalue(soeField, sum, "dataset")) of previous page in next page?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed page size eg A4 you can calculate the page totals (as you will be able to work out the number of rows per page). Define Brought forward, Carried Forward, Page Total and Page Number as a fields in your data set. This is more powerfull in settings where for example you want to print a set of customer statements in a single print run. Each customer statement would need its own page numbers and totals. You can use ReportItems![Cell Name] to display these values in the relevant part of the report as they would appear at the detail level of the dataset. In this case you add hidden field(s) containing the values you require on the detail line and pick them up using ReportItems. You can also force a page break at the end of each Page number group and a report Header / footer to display relevant totals or alternatively define a header and footer with the Page group to display these values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ewan.
this solution below was very helpful to my issue. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/86162230-d2cf-44d2-a496-e2c17d7accc5/forum-faq-how-do-i-get-the-subtotals-of-each-page-and-previous-pages-at-the-bottom-of-the-report?forum=sqlreportingservices